# How to close and iconify a JavaFx stage

Tags: java, javafx

In my Java Fx application I create a two stages. The first stage is the default in the main controller class, `HomeController`. The second, `AddNewEmailController`, is created by calling a method, `showNewComposeNewEmail()`, in the `AddNewEmailController` class.

The new stage gets created fine, but none of the methods I try to call, like closing the `AddNewEmailController` stage, will work on the `AddNewEmailController` stage.

How can I get the methods to work?

I'd also like to have the `HomeController` stage inaccessible once the `AddNewEmailController` stage gets open, like how pop-up windows do.

I can't even get the `AddNewEmailController` stage to ***iconify***?

Thank you all in advance.

***The HomeController class:***

```
public class HomeController implements Initializable {

// Initializes the controller class.
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}
@FXML
public void windowClose() {
    Platform.exit();
}

@FXML
public void showNewComposeNewEmail() throws Exception {
    new AddNewEmailController().newnewcomposeNewEmailStage();
}
}
```

***The AddNewEmailController class:***

```
public class AddNewEmailController implements Initializable {

public void setScreenParent(ScreensController screenParent) {
    myController = screenParent;
}

// Initializes the controller class.
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}

public Stage newComposeNewEmail;

public void newnewcomposeNewEmailStage() throws IOException {
    newComposeNewEmail = new Stage();
    newComposeNewEmail.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    newComposeNewEmail.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

    Parent newComposeNewEmailRoot = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/wakiliproject/Forms/AddNew/NewEmail/NewEmail.fxml"));

    StageDraggable.stageDraggable(newComposeNewEmailRoot, newComposeNewEmail);

    Scene newComposeNewEmailScene = new Scene(newComposeNewEmailRoot, 590, 670);

    newComposeNewEmail.setScene(newComposeNewEmailScene);
    newComposeNewEmail.show();
}

@FXML
private void newComposeNewEmailClose() {
    newComposeNewEmail.close();
}

@FXML
private void newComposeNewEmailIconify() {
    newComposeNewEmail.setIconified(true);
}
}
```

***UPDATE:***

*The NewEmail FXML:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="wakiliproject.Forms.AddNew.NewEmail.TryEMailController">
  <children>
    <Label layoutX="190.0" layoutY="61.0" onMouseClicked="#newComposeNewEmailStageIconify" text="Minimise Window" />
    <Label layoutX="300.0" layoutY="61.0" onMouseClicked="#newComposeNewEmailStageClose" text="Close Window" />
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: How are you calling `newComposeNewEmailClose()` ?

Comment: Hi [@ItachiUchiha](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1759128/itachiuchiha). Thanks for looking at my question. I attach the `newComposeNewEmailClose()` method to a Label\ Button to the AddNewEmail FXML file using JavaFx SceneBuilder

Comment: Hmm, that should work, can you attach your FXML as well ?

Comment: Hi [@ItachiUchiha](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1759128/itachiuchiha). I just added the NewEmail FXML. Hope you can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fxml, your `controller` is

`fx:controller="wakiliproject.Forms.AddNew.NewEmail.TryEMailController"`

while in your code, the class name is

```
AddNewEmailController
```

Please make them same and recheck, your method will be called.

For making the new Stage as child of the Parent, please use

```
newStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
newStage.initOwner(PrimaryStage);
```

Comment: Thank you. That was great help.